# How to bind command in ViewModel to a command in Behavior?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism-7

WPF project + Prism 7 + (Pure MVVM pattern)

Simple, I have `TextBox` which need to be cleared when some button is pressed (without the violation to the MVVM pattern)

```
<Button Command="{Binding ClearCommand}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding File}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ClearTextBehavior ClearTextCommand="{Binding ClearCommand, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel {
    public ICommand ClearCommand { get; set; }
}
```

**Behavior**

```
public class ClearTextBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    public ICommand ClearTextCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ClearTextCommandProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ClearTextCommandProperty, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(); 
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClearTextCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(ClearTextCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(ClearTextBehavior));

    public ClearTextBehavior()
    {
        ClearTextCommand = new DelegateCommand(ClearTextCommandExecuted);
    }

    private void ClearTextCommandExecuted()
    {
        this.AssociatedObject.Clear();
    }
}
```

The problem is the command in the ViewModel is always null (it did not bound to the command in the Behavior), Although I made sure that it is initialized in the behavior class.

**NOTE: please do NOT suggest to set the File property to empty string, because this is just an example, In my real case, I need to select all the Text, so I really need an access to the `AssociatedObject` of the behavior**

Comment: ClearCommand is null in your viewmodel there.

Comment: @Andy yes, and I do not know why, it should be the bound from the behavior, but it does not

Comment: Do you want to solve your SelectAllText problem or this command problem (which you think will solve your SelectAllText problem)?

Comment: @SirRufo the main problem is SelectAllText, I want to solve this problem

Comment: Then you should rewrite your question: How to ... SelectAllText? I tried with ... but no success.

Comment: I think you missed my point. Unless you set ClearCommand to some sort of a command then it will be null. Are you setting it to anything? Because there's nothing in your code does that. All you do is define the property.

Comment: @Andy I am not setting it in the code, but I am binding it like this `<local:ClearTextBehavior ClearTextCommand="{Binding ClearCommand, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />` see the XAML code above

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your Question correctly, you want to know why the `ICommand` in the `ViewModel` is not set to the `DelegateCommand` defined in the `Behaviour`.

The Problem is, that the `ICommand` and the `DelegateCommand` do not have a direct connection. I assume you may misunderstood how a `Binding` works and what happens by using those.

First of all, the `ICommand` is 'comes' from a `Class` and is therefore a reference Type.

Second, the reference to the `ICommand` is saved within the `DependencyProperty` `ClearTextCommandProperty`.

Third, by using a `Binding` in the `XAML` something like this happens as C# code:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("ClearTextCommand");
binding.Source = ClearCommand; 
BindingOperations.SetBinding(TextBox.ClearTextCommandProperty, binding);
```

Now the important thing: I don't know exactly which assignment comes first, but both lines will override the `Value` reference in the `ClearTextCommandProperty`!

```
//either here
SetBinding(TextBox.ClearTextCommandProperty, binding);

//or here 
ClearTextCommand = new DelegateCommand(ClearTextCommandExecuted);
//Which could be written as
SetValue(ClearTextCommandProperty, new DelegateCommand(ClearTextCommandExecuted));
```

At no point there is an assignment like this:

```
ViewModel.ClearCommand = SomeICommand;
```

Therefore it is `Null`, as @Andy mentioned

---

**Edited to match select all Text**

Additionally, i suggest you drop this complex stuff and use the full potential of the `Interactivity` Package like this:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <utils:SelectAllText TargetName="TextToSelect"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>

<TextBox x:Name="TextToSelect" Text="{Binding File}"/>
```

And the `SelectAllText`

```
public class SelectAllText : TargetedTriggerAction<TextBox>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        if (Target == null) return;

        Target.SelectAll();
        Target.Focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at this sample here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31915.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-1.aspx
You will notice that I have an ICommand there and it's set up to run a method.

If it was just an ICommand with a Get and Set like you have there then it would be NULL. There's a property but it's null until it is set to something.

This a very clunky way to implement an ICommand but relies on no external libraries or anything.

If you take a look at the second article in that series, it uses mvvmlight and relaycommand so creating a command is rather less clunky.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32164.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-2.aspx

```
public RelayCommand AddListCommand { get; set; }

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    AddListCommand = new RelayCommand(AddList);
}
private void AddList()
{
    stringList.Add(myString));
}
```

If you look at that code AddListCommand is initially null.
It is set in the constructor to a new RelayCommand which means it is then not null.

This is fairly simple but the code for the command is in a different place to the property so a more elegant approach is usual. As shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn237302.aspx

---

Having said all that.
Selecting all text is something to do in the view, not the viewmodel.
You shouldn't really be passing a piece of UI from the view into a viewmodel.

Rather than a command it could well be that you should be binding a bool which is set in the viewmodel and acted on in the behaviour.